# Wireless adapter not recognized on linux-5.4.48

Tags: linux, kernel, wifi

I'm using USB Wi-Fi adapter `TL-WN722N`.  With linux kernels up to `5.4.38`, it used to work fine.  After `5.4.38 -> 5.4.48` upgrade, it does not light up and won't show up in `/sys/class/net`.  Why could this be?

Kernel config is virtually the same.  Here's the exact diff:

```
--- #<buffer .config<linux-5.4.38-gentoo>>
+++ #<buffer .config<linux>>
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 #
 # Automatically generated file; DO NOT EDIT.
-# Linux/x86 5.4.38-gentoo Kernel Configuration
+# Linux/x86 5.4.48-gentoo Kernel Configuration
 #
 
 #
@@ -12,7 +12,6 @@
 CONFIG_CC_CAN_LINK=y
 CONFIG_CC_HAS_ASM_GOTO=y
 CONFIG_CC_HAS_ASM_INLINE=y
-CONFIG_CC_HAS_WARN_MAYBE_UNINITIALIZED=y
 CONFIG_IRQ_WORK=y
 CONFIG_BUILDTIME_EXTABLE_SORT=y
 CONFIG_THREAD_INFO_IN_TASK=y
```

Notes:

- I always had relevant bits built into kernel, not installed as modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the kernel bugtracker](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=208251),  the problem was introduced in 5.4.47 and resolved in 5.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

Kernel bisect (google for it) might tell you which patch has broken your WiFi adapter. Before starting to bisect make absolutely sure that the old kernel works and the new one doesn't.

Rebooting is probably not necessary if you're able to `sudo rmmod kernel_module_for_your_wifi` but then it's probable that changes outside of WiFi have caused this regression.